# Java File Object equivalent in C#

Tags: java, c#, file

Well, the title says it, I want to know if there is any Object Wrappers equivalent to that in C#.

What I want to do is create a sub-directory, inside the parent directory, of a file provided by the user. In Java I would do:

```
JFileChooser chooser=new JFileChooser(new File("."));
chooser.showOpenDialog();
File selectedFile=chooser.getSelectedFile();
File subDir=new File(selectedFile.getParentFile(), "subdir_name");
subDir.mkdir();
```

What would be the equivalent in C#? Or, maybe I need to do a different work-around by using the file path?

Comment: Use [`FileInfo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.fileinfo(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Have you looked at the `FileInfo` and `DirectoryInfo` classes?

Comment: Look into [DirectoryInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h8dtw1d6(v=vs.110).aspx) class.

Comment: If you're developing a WinForms application, there's the [FileDialog](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.filedialog(v=vs.110).aspx) class you can use to ask the user to select a file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Perhaps something like this?

```
String InitialDir = "c:\\";
String DirFilter = "txt files (*.txt)|*.txt|All files (*.*)|*.*";

OpenFileDialog myDialog = new OpenFileDialog
{
    InitialDirectory = InitialDir,
    Filter = DirFilter,
    FilterIndex = 2,
    RestoreDirectory = true,
};            

if(myDialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
{
    try
    {
        FileInfo myFile = new FileInfo(myDialog.FileName);
        Directory.CreateDirectory(Path.Combine(myFile.DirectoryName, "subdir_name"));                    
    }
    catch 
    { 
        // exception handling here
        throw;
    }
}
```